# Is it possible to free a memory occupied by primitive data type forcefully using free() in C++?

Tags: c++, c, class, free

I was trying to free a memory occupied by primitive variable to learn about the working procesdure of free(). Then the compiler raised an error:

> "error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void*' [-fpermissive] free(a);"

```
void test::freeMemory(){
    
    int a = 100;
    double b = 123.456f;
    
    cout << "Value of x before free: " << a << endl;
    cout << "Value of y before free: " << b << endl;
    
    free(a);
    free(b);

}
```

Comment: No that's not possible. `free` only works on memory returned by either `malloc` or `calloc`. Memory occupied by variables (of any sort) is managed by the compiler, not by you. Note that `free(ptr)` releases the memory pointed to by the variable `ptr`, not the memory occupied by the variable itself. This confusion between the pointer and what it is pointing to is **extremely** common in newbies learning about pointers.

Comment: `free` should be used only for **pointers** and only for ones acquired from a dynamic memory allocation function from the `malloc` family.

Comment: @msahmedme You're welcome. I should have added that you can use `free` on memory returned by `realloc` as well as `malloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: The memory used for local variables will be automatically be released at the function exit. The `a` and `b` do not exist after the function execution ends.

Comment: You can do it, but not using `free()`. Just put the variables inside a scope by introducing a block like this: `{ int a; /* do whatever with a */ }`. All automatic (stack) variables declared inside a block `{ ... }` are destroyed at the end of the block.

Comment: @Galik Their lifetimes end, but 1) the stack is usually adjusted once and for all at the entry and exit of a function, and 2) primitives are usually stored in registers so there's no memory to release.

Comment: @molbdnilo True, but it gives the compiler information that gives it the opportunity to make more efficient use of the stack by reusing memory that is only occupied inside *local scopes*.  Not exactly the same thing, but still potentially a bit of a win.

Answer (score 1):

No, `free()` is used to deallocate dynamic memory, and it is undefined behavior to call it with an address of any variable that is not allocated via `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

In C, you would could dynamically allocate them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
*a = 100;
free(a);
```

In C++, you don't want to use free (or delete) but instead rely on automatic deallocation of a smart pointer (`unique_ptr`) when it's out of scope:

```
{
    auto a = std::make_unique(100);
}
```